# MYSQL select the monday of two weeks ago

Tags: mysql, date, time

How do I select not last Monday, but the Monday before, for use in a where statement like so:

```
WHERE DATE(ramses.batch_log.start_time) < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

So, two weeks ago, but not from Today(Wednesday), from Monday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** cleaner and correct one:

```
WHERE DATE(ramses.batch_log.start_time) < SUBDATE(SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY), INTERVAL 2 WEEK);
```

Comment: This seems to select last Friday.